# MS EDGE is URL encoding an AJAX POST call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, microsoft-edge

I have an $.ajax call that is getting encoded with URL encoding.
One thing I need to specify is this only happens in Microsoft Edge.  Chrome and Firefox work fine with no issues.

Here is my Ajax call

```
var promise = $.ajax({
   url: "/webapp/CustomPricing/StartPricing",
   type: "POST",
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: {
      "model": JSON.stringify(this.model),
      "numHandlingUnits": this.handlingUnitsCount,
      "handlingUnits": this.commoditiesCount
   },
   xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
   }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: jQuery does all the encoding before the request gets sent. In this case what is sent will be identical to `$.param(yourdataobjecthere)`

Comment: And it won't match the contentType you set, a param string isn't json.

Comment: How should I change my request then?  Also this issue only exists in MS-EDGE.  Chrome, IE and Firefox work with no issues.

Comment: Depends. What did you expect it to do? As it is, your request doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"` with `data: { some: 'object'}` is a mismatch. The data you are sending isn't in the format you are telling the server it is in.

Comment: Currently the request is getting sent in URL Encoding which causes it to fail.  On all other browsers the request works fine, however in MS-edge it fails.  I'd like to figure out why Edge is encoding it and fix that.

Comment: That's not what i'm asking! What is this request supposed to be doing? is it supposed to be sending JSON? form params? something else? It workign in browser X and not Y is just a symptom, for all we know browser X is wrong.

Comment: I removed the 2nd and 3rd line from the data section so its only "model": JSON.stringify(this.model) and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be sending JSON form params.

Comment: gah, there's no such thing as JSON form params.

Comment: Form params is a urlencoded format. The values being urlencoded would be expected, even if the param contained a json string. If you're sending form params, the contentType would need to be removed, because it's wrong.

Comment: Guess that is my fault for walking into that one.  It is sending a large JSON array full of form fields.

Comment: Then you'll want to JSON.stringify the whole object, as suggested in the answer below. and you'll want to not JSON.stringify model, because then you'd have it double encoded (unless that's what your server was expecting)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) around data

```
JSON.stringify({
  "model": JSON.stringify(this.model),
  "numHandlingUnits": this.handlingUnitsCount,
  "handlingUnits": this.commoditiesCount
})
```

Comment: This fixed my issue getting the data to the server.

Comment: As @KevinB mentioned, probably don't want to stringify `this.model` *and* the entire object.